# How to install List view command set extension in a site collection after deploying it to app catalog using CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions, listviewcommandset

I have created a ListView command set extension using SPFx and upload it in the app catalog. Now I want to install this extension for only particular sites.

I tried adding it as a custom action but it is not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
CustomActionEntity ca = new CustomActionEntity
                {
                    Title = "HelloWorld",
                    RegistrationId = "101",
                    RegistrationType = UserCustomActionRegistrationType.List,
                    Location = "ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet.CommandBar",
                    ClientSideComponentId = spfxExtensionGlobalHeaderId,
                    ClientSideComponentProperties = "{&quot;sampleTextOne&quot;:&quot;One item is selected in the list.&quot;, &quot;sampleTextTwo&quot;:&quot;This command is always visible.&quot;}"
                };

         currentWeb.AddCustomAction(ca);
```

Comment: how did you tried to add it? Like we add any other app from Site Content?

Comment: Also, please add the error you are getting.

Comment: i am not getting any error but the command is not visible in the command after executing the code.

Comment: Added code snippet used for adding as custom action.

Comment: Did you try by adding the package manually in app catalog?

Comment: If I do manually everything is working fine, I am able to add an application to app catalog and install the app from the site collection. I am unable to add the app using csom.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully installed the extension using PnP App manager class.

```
AppManager appManager = new AppManager(clientContext);
var apps = appManager.GetAvailable();
foreach (var app in apps)
{
if (app.Title == "List View Command Set")
{
    appManager.Install(app);
}
}
```